# Does Spring Security OAuth2 support Authorization Code Flow with PKCE for browser (Angular) clients?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Browser applications auth used to be managed using the Implicit grant of the Authorization Server. I successfully implemented this using [Spring Security Oauth](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html).

This approach has several drawbacks:

1. Refresh tokens are not supported, so when the token expires we need to reauthenticate with the Authorization server.
2. This grant is not recommended due to its security concerns (see https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/ and https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-parecki-oauth-browser-based-apps-01).

Currently the recommended option is using Authorization code flow with PKCE for browser applications.

How could this be implemented in a Spring Boot Authorization Server with spring boot oauth?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it does not yet support PKCE, though [there is a ticket for it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4943).

Note also that Spring Security's OAuth support is in a bit of a transition phase right now while it is migrated into Spring Security proper. Feel free to follow [this feature matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix) to see where progress is at.

**UPDATE**: Spring Authorization Server now supports [this feature](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/426).

Comment: Thanks @jzheaux, but would you know why PKCE can't be found in this matrix ? Is it included in one of the listed feature ?

Comment: ok the ticket now says: The Spring Security team has decided to no longer provide support for Authorization Servers. As a result one still can implement a resource server using Spring and even an authentication server by embedding keycloack or any similar authentication provider server.

Comment: Spring Security subsequently reversed that decision, and introduced Spring Authorization Server. Details about PKCE support are here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/426